# NextJs 13 Link not navigating to sections

Tags: next.js

I have sections that should be scrolled to when navigating to them such as /#testimonials. It is working fine when I use the anchor tag but not the Link tag.

```
export function Testimonials() {
  return (
    <section
      id="testimonials"
      aria-label="What our customers are saying"
      className="bg-slate-50 py-20 sm:py-32"
    >
       ...
    </section>
  )
}
```

I'm using Links as follows

```
     <div className="hidden md:flex md:gap-x-6">
        <Link href="/#features">Features</Link>
        <Link href="/#testimonials">Testimonials</Link>
        <Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Link>
     </div>
```

The link in the url bar changes but it does not scroll to the section.

Why does it work with the anchor tag and not the Link tag?

Next Info:

```bash
    Operating System:
      Platform: linux
      Arch: x64
      Version: #36-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb 3 18:36:56 UTC 2023
    Binaries:
      Node: 16.19.1
      npm: 8.19.3
      Yarn: N/A
      pnpm: N/A
    Relevant packages:
      next: 13.2.4
      eslint-config-next: 13.2.4
      react: 18.2.0
      react-dom: 18.2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65086176/19019306) the differnce between the `a` and `Link` is:

### `a` tag:

> (a) tag without using next/link's  creates a standard hyperlink which directs (the) end user to the url as a new page. (standard behavior).

### `Link` component:

> However,  will create a (a) tag, which means your links will be detected when crawlers scrape your site. End users will still navigate with without reloading the page, creating the behavior of a Single Page App.

So the reason it doesn't work using the `Link` component is that a full reload is being performed.

Comment: I do know the differences between `<a>` and `Link` but I don't believe this gets at the question. Using Next 12 or under, navigating to sections using the `Link` component does work as expected. I believe this is an issue specific to Next 13 and above.

Comment: Are you using the experimental ``app``` directory?

Comment: Yeah, I am using the App dir, I’m wondering if maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: Please run the command ```next info``` in your project root directory and put the results in your question. That way I can get more details about your configuration.

Comment: I just added the information to the question

Comment: Try running ```npm install next@canary``` and see if that fixes your issue. Sometimes issues with Next 13 are fixed using a ```canary``` version.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in the upcoming release of Next.js `v13.4.5`, they have addressed a problem related to relative query and hash handling in both the `next/link` component and the router push/replace methods.

You can give it a try with the pre-release version [13.4.5-canary.1](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v13.4.5-canary.1#:%7E:text=App%20Router%3A%20fix%20relative%20query/hash%20handling%20in%20next/link%20and%20router%20push/replace%3A) and see if you'll be to use the `Link` tag for scrolling to sections e.g. `<Link href="#testimonials">`.